# How to excecute flush commands on stackexchange redis client using c#

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

How can we excecute FlushAll and FlushDB redis commands using stackexchange redis client?

Comment: Not sure this really deserves 4 downvotes, but...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [project homepage](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) has a [Documentation section](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/), which includes [Where are KEYS, SCAN, FLUSHDB etc?](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan)

The short answer is: via `IServer`. The documentation includes the "why".

```
// get the target server
var server = conn.GetServer(someServer);

// completely wipe ALL keys from database 0
server.FlushDatabase(); // database number is optional and defaults to 0
```