# how can I delete all the key-value in redis through StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, stackexchange

I  use StackExchange.Redis in C# program. Is there any method to clear redis or delete all key-value pairs?

Comment: Related / Possible Dupe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074788/how-to-excecute-flush-commands-on-stackexchange-redis-client-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [`FLUSHDB`](https://redis.io/commands/flushdb) / [`FLUSHALL`](https://redis.io/commands/flushall). Despite the name, this is not a "database" level command, but rather is a "server" level command (meaning: in the context of a redis cluster, it only impacts one server, not the entire keyspace; [this distinction is explained more here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan)), hence it is accessed from `IServer` in SE.Redis:

```
ConnexctionMultiplexer redis = ...
var server = redis.GetServer({your server here});
server.FlushDatabase(); // or await server.FlushDatabaseAsync();
```